# Linear dependency and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

**Statement:**

Let **$V$** be a vectorial space, $T: V  \to V$ a linear operator, u is a eigenvector of T associated to eigenvalue $\lambda$ and v a eigenvector T associated to eigenvalue $\alpha$ .

a) If $\lambda \neq \alpha$, then u and v can be linearly dependent.

My question is: Why is this not true?

**What I tried to do:**

My approach to this question was:

There's a matrix A associated with T so that Au = $\lambda$u and Av = $\alpha$v. Also, for some $\beta$, it's true that $\beta$v = u.
So I tried to do some math with those, but could not get anywhere...
Any hints on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Distinct eigenvalues means distinct eigenspaces, so if one vector is in the complement of the eigenspace of the other vector's eigenvalue, it must be linearly independent of the vectors in that space. Why do you think this is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly trivial. Assuming $u \neq 0, v \neq 0$:

$Au = \lambda u \space \mathrm {and}\space Av = \alpha v \space \mathrm {and}\space u=\beta v \implies \lambda u = A(\beta v) = \beta Av = \beta \alpha v = \alpha (\beta v) = \alpha u \implies \lambda = \alpha$

$\beta$ cannot be null because it $\beta = 0$ and $u=\beta v \implies u =0$